# Allow lambda to assume role of an IAM Role that was created from identity pool?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, amazon-iam

I am trying to exchange the token that was given to me by the amazon cognito for a role that is defined on Identity pool, using "assume_role_with_web_identity" of boto3 but it gives me this error:

"botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity operation: Access denied"

I must have missed something on the policy?

I already tried to change the policy for the lambda, to this:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogStream"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:logs:us-west-2:xxx:log-group:/aws/lambda/xxx:*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow"
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "logs:PutLogEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:logs:us-west-2:xxx:log-group:/aws/lambda/rxx:*:*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "PermitAssumeRole",
            "Action": [
                "sts:AssumeRole"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:iam::xxx:role/Auth_Role",
                "arn:aws:iam::xxx:role/Cognito_Unauth_Role"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

My code on the boto3:

```
x = trial.assume_role_with_web_identity(RoleArn="arn:aws:iam::xxx:role/xxx",
                                         RoleSessionName="xx",WebIdentityToken=response['xx']['xx'])
```

I expect it to be able to assume the role of the IAM I created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @franziga said, separate your trust policy (the `PermitAssumeRole` statement) from the rest of the policy (which is the permissions policy). Also your trust policy, if Lambda needs to take that role, needs to be like

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

ALso, if you want your `Lambda` to have same access as permissions in your `Cognito authenticated` & `unauthenticated` roles, you would have to add those permissions in role for Lambda. As far as I know, you cannot attach a role to another role.

Comment: I can only get this to work if add the full arn of the lambda's execution role to the "Principal", e.g. "Principal": { "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::123456789:role/my-app-lambdaRole", "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"}.  I can't seem to get it to take any wildcards in the arn either. Any thoughts on other pieces I might be missing?

Comment: The above trust policy is a working policy we use with many lambda functions. I do not see the need for `AWS` descriptor in `Principal`. What happens if you eliminate that? Any chance you can paste your IAM role?

Comment: If I eliminate that I get 'An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the AssumeRole operation: Access denied: ClientError'. I am calling sts service assume_role as shown here: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cognito-user-pool-group/

Answer (score 0):

Trust policy should be separated from permission policy.